# How to write items from a ListBox into an Array VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

In a userform I want the `CommandButton1_Click` to basically take whatever is in the listbox and put into an array I set `As Variant`. `ComandButton2_Click` takes whatever the user selects in the ComboBox and inserts it into the ListBox. But I am doing this with my final array I want to take away called `SelectedTitles`.

```vb
Public SelectedTitles As Variant, ArrCount As Long, EnableEvents As Boolean

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Size As Integer
    Size = ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    ReDim SelectedTitles(0 To Size) As Variant
    Dim x As Integer
    
    For x = 0 To Size
        SelectedTitles(x) = ListBox1.Value(x)
    Next x
    
    'Done Button
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    'User has indicated they want to add the currently selected item to the list
    If Not EnableEvents Then Exit Sub
    If ArrCount = 0 Then 'First item, create the array
        SelectedTitles = Array("")
    Else
        ReDim Preserve SelectedTitles(UBound(SelectedTitles) + 1) 'Next items, add one more space in the array
    End If
    
    ListBox1.AddItem (ComboBox1.Value)
    
    'Increment the counter
    ArrCount = ArrCount + 1
    
    'Reset the checkbox and the combobox
    EnableEvents = False
    CommandButton2.Value = False
    ComboBox1.Value = ""
    EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I am getting error 'type mismatch'

```vb
SelectedTitles(x) = ListBox1.Value(x)
```

Comment: it says `SelectedTitles(x)=""` and `ListBox1.Value(x)=<Type Mismatch>`

Comment: Please, try replacing `SelectedTitles(x) = ListBox1.Value(x)` with `SelectedTitles(x) = ListBox1.list(x)`. `ListBox1.Value(x)` makes no sense in VBA. `Value` refers to selected row, list box `boundColumn`. No index to be used.